# How do i push objects into the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

I am having trouble applying objects to my array, every time i push the object into the array a new array is created.

I have made some edits at the bottom of the question.

I need an array of objects to look like this

```
var arr = [{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'}, { name:'benny', town:'vegas'}];
```

Insted mine looks like this

```
var arr = [0:{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'}1:{ name:'benny', town:'vegas'}]
```

PHP

```
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare("SELECT ctc_coins_name, "
        . " ctc_coins_town "
        . " FROM ctc_coins ");
$stmt->execute();
$result_coins = $stmt->fetchAll();

$coins = [];
foreach ($result_coins as $result) {
    $coins[] = [
        'name' => $result['ctc_coins_name'],
        'twon' => $result['ctc_coins_town]
    ];
}
echo json_encode($coins);
```

Javascript

```
function update_local_coins() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "pages/ajax/getCoins.php";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
            if (this.responseText) {
                jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(jsonObj);
                var coins = [];
                for (var l in jsonObj) {
                    coins.push(jsonObj[l]);
                }
                console.log("COINS");
                console.log(coins);
            } else {
                alert("Noobs");
            }
        }
    };
    http.send();
}
```

I have tried this with no luck

```
coins.concat(jsonObj[l]) 'returns empty array'
coins.push.apply(coins, jsonObj[l]) 'returns empty array'
coins.push(jsonObj[l]) 'returns the example array'
```

EDIT:

```
console.log(jsonObj);
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{name: "Bitcoin", usd: "5622.73", btc: "1.00000000"}
1
:
{name: "Ethereum", usd: "338.81", btc: "0.06013390"}
2
:
{name: "Litecoin", usd: "58.65", btc: "0.01040990"}
3
:
{name: "Dash", usd: "307.31", btc: "0.05454360"}
4
:
{name: "Golem", usd: "0.21", btc: "0.00003759"}
5
:
{name: "NEM", usd: "0.21", btc: "0.00003674"}
6
:
{name: "Neutron", usd: "0.15", btc: "0.00002686"}
7
:
{name: "DigiByte", usd: "0.01", btc: "0.00000175"}
8
:
{name: "Siacoin", usd: "0.00", btc: "0.00000074"}
9
:
{name: "Linda", usd: "0.00", btc: "0.00000005"}
10
:
{name: "LiteDoge", usd: "0.00", btc: "0.00000001"}
11
:
{name: "ArcticCoin", usd: "0.05", btc: "0.00000922"}
12
:
{name: "NoLimitCoin", usd: "0.13", btc: "0.00002321"}
length
:
13
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

EDIT: php echo json

```
[{"name":"Bitcoin","usd":"5622.73","btc":"1.00000000"},{"name":"Ethereum","usd":"338.81","btc":"0.06013390"},{"name":"Litecoin","usd":"58.65","btc":"0.01040990"},{"name":"Dash","usd":"307.31","btc":"0.05454360"},{"name":"Golem","usd":"0.21","btc":"0.00003759"},{"name":"NEM","usd":"0.21","btc":"0.00003674"},{"name":"Neutron","usd":"0.15","btc":"0.00002686"},{"name":"DigiByte","usd":"0.01","btc":"0.00000175"},{"name":"Siacoin","usd":"0.00","btc":"0.00000074"},{"name":"Linda","usd":"0.00","btc":"0.00000005"},{"name":"LiteDoge","usd":"0.00","btc":"0.00000001"},{"name":"ArcticCoin","usd":"0.05","btc":"0.00000922"},{"name":"NoLimitCoin","usd":"0.13","btc":"0.00002321"}]
```

Comment: In your PHP code, ```$arr[]``` is an array of associate arrays. ```json_encode``` will turn them into JSON array of objects. So when you execute ```jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);```, you should be getting the array of objects you wanted. Would be helpful if you could give us the output of ```console.log(jsonObj);``` as well.

Comment: 0
:
{name: "Bitcoin", usd: "5622.73", btc: "1.00000000"}
1
:
{name: "Ethereum", usd: "338.81", btc: "0.06013390"}
2
:
{name: "Litecoin", usd: "58.65", btc: "0.01040990"}
3
:
{name: "Dash", usd: "307.31", btc: "0.05454360"}
4
:
{name: "Golem", usd: "0.21", btc: "0.00003759"}
5
:
{name: "NEM", usd: "0.21", btc: "0.00003674"}
6
:
{name: "Neutron", usd: "0.15", btc: "0.00002686"}
7
:
{name: "DigiByte", usd: "0.01", btc: "0.00000175"}
8
:
{name: "Siacoin", usd: "0.00", btc: "0.00000074"}

This is the console.log

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for asking this, but could also send the output of ```echo json_encode($coins);```. You can add this to the question actually. It would be helpful for anyone trying to answer this.

Comment: Edited now so that both the echo and the json enocde is visible

Comment: So i should not parse the responseText, but just use it as it is, interesting but now that it looks like it should, how do i tell it that it is an array?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below. It has an attached code snippet which should answer your doubts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156736/discussion-between-kkaosninja-and-ii-iml0sto1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective was to get the array of objects received in the AJAX response.

As I said in my first comment to your question, you already got this in this line

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Now, you seem to think that you have received an object(with numbers being fields, and the objects being values). But this is just how console.log behaves :)

As for your final question regarding a way to confirm that is indeed an array, all you need to do is check the string representation of the result of `JSON.parse()` i.e use `JSON.stringify`. Below example demonstrates this.

EDIT: Have updated code snippet with demonstration of `findMatches()` posted in the comment.

```js
        var s = '[{"name":"Bitcoin","usd":"5622.73","btc":"1.00000000"},{"name":"Ethereum","usd":"338.81","btc":"0.06013390"},{"name":"Litecoin","usd":"58.65","btc":"0.01040990"},{"name":"Dash","usd":"307.31","btc":"0.05454360"},{"name":"Golem","usd":"0.21","btc":"0.00003759"},{"name":"NEM","usd":"0.21","btc":"0.00003674"},{"name":"Neutron","usd":"0.15","btc":"0.00002686"},{"name":"DigiByte","usd":"0.01","btc":"0.00000175"},{"name":"Siacoin","usd":"0.00","btc":"0.00000074"},{"name":"Linda","usd":"0.00","btc":"0.00000005"},{"name":"LiteDoge","usd":"0.00","btc":"0.00000001"},{"name":"ArcticCoin","usd":"0.05","btc":"0.00000922"},{"name":"NoLimitCoin","usd":"0.13","btc":"0.00002321"}]';
    
        var arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(s);
    
        var stringifiedArray = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects);
    
        document.getElementById("op").innerText = stringifiedArray;
    
        function findMatches(arr, searchString) {
            const matches = [];
            arr.forEach(obj => {
                for(const key in obj) {
                if (obj[key].includes(searchString)) {
                    matches.push(obj[key]);
                }
            }
        });
            return matches;
        }
    
    var matches = findMatches(arrayOfObjects, "Lite");
    
    document.getElementById("mr").innerText = JSON.stringify(matches);
```

```html
<p id="op">

    <!-- Result of JSON.stringify will appear here -->

    </p>
    <hr>
    <p id="mr">
    <!-- Result of findMatches will appear here -->
    </p>
```

Comment: But its still not an array? i am using this example to sort it

`function findMatches(arr, searchString){
  const matches = [];

  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (obj[key].includes(searchString)){
        matches.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  });

  return matches;
}`

It works with this array of objects 

`const arr = [
{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'},
 {name:'benny', town:'vegas'}
];` but does not work with the result we make

Comment: Edited code snippet and added your function. Please run it. You will see that it works as expected. In the example, I search for "Lite". I get the results as "Litecoin" and "LiteDoge"

Comment: Please do the mark the answer as correct if you feel it answered your question.

Comment: Just 1 more question before marking as correct, how can i make it non case sensetive? like if a person enters litecoin or Litecoin it should show Litecoin

Comment: I would recommend calling ```lowerCase()``` on both the strings, before calling ```includes()```, which should solve your problem.

Comment: Do you mean toLowerCase()? and where exactly should i put this?

Comment: Will leave this to you as an exercise :). Hint: where the string comparison takes place.